# how do I remove the blank line without any data?

Tags: ansible

How to remove empty lines in the output list for below playbook? then i need to store only mac address & port information in variable, can i remove it in ansible it self or do i need to use any other method?

Playbook,

```
- name: Print Converted Mac
  set_fact:
    mac_array: "{{ sw_mac.results | json_query('[*].stdout') }}"

- name: Query the mac on the switch
  ios_command:
    commands: show mac address-table | in {{ item }}
  with_items: "{{ mac_array }}"
  ignore_errors: yes
  register: mac_array_result

- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.stdout }}"
  with_items: "{{ mac_array_result.results }}"
  when: item.stdout | length > 1
  register: comout

- set_fact:
    mac_port: "{{ comout | json_query('results[*].item.stdout') | list }}"
```

Output: list of the mac_port

```
ok: [10.10.10.177] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "mac_port": [
            [
                "201    44a8.4227.c7ba    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/13"
            ],
            [
                ""
            ],

            [
                ""
            ]
        ]
    },
    "changed": false
}
```

as requested Based on the ask here is the code which is the output of the comout.results variable for single item which has data in line, and others are without the lines. Now how can we only print item which is has data in line.

```
{
  "ansible_loop_var": "item",
  "changed": false,
  "item": {
    "ansible_facts": {
      "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    },
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "failed": false,
    "invocation": {
      "module_args": {
        "auth_pass": null,
        "authorize": null,
        "commands": [
          "show mac address-table | in 44a8.4227.c7ba"
        ],
        "host": null,
        "interval": 1,
        "match": "all",
        "password": null,
        "port": null,
        "provider": null,
        "retries": 10,
        "ssh_keyfile": null,
        "timeout": null,
        "username": null,
        "wait_for": null
      }
    },
    "item": "44a8.4227.c7ba",
    "stdout": [
      "201    44a8.4227.c7ba    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/13"
    ],
    "stdout_lines": [
      [
        "201    44a8.4227.c7ba    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/13"
      ]
    ]
  },
  "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False",
  "skipped": true
}
```

Comment: Can you provide value of,  mac_array_result.results.stdout, without with item, looks like it's iterating over 1 st element only which contains all data.

Comment: mac_array_result.results.stdout --when i am trying to print this it is giving error.

Comment: but i am getting mac_array_result.results do you want to check that?

Comment: "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleUnicode object' has no attribute 'stdout'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/ansible-vmware/vmwarehost-config-playbooks/stackoverflow.yaml': line 38, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - debug:\n      ^ here\n"
}

Comment: yes, can you provide the value of mac_array_result or mac_array_result.results

Comment: I was trying to edit and share the output of the mac_array_result or mac_array_result.results but stackoverflow is not allowing...since content is too big..

Comment: okay then you can edit output and try to put result formate (mainly brackets) or formate something like "Output: list of the mac_port" block of your question (only the 1st block will important to understand)

Comment: i have added the output for single item please check.

Comment: Hi mac_port is dynamic value here you have define static..hence it will not solve the issue.

Comment: Yes that was an example, you Just add last two task from my answer at the end of your playbook and it should work.   Also you need to replace p with p[0] in this following two lines.        {% if p != "" %} {% set _ = new_mac_port.append(p) %}

Comment: thanks after making the changes it works..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to remove empty lines, then you can use something line this,

```
---
  - hosts: localhost
    vars:
      mac_port:
        - "201    44a8.4227.c7ba    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/13"
        - ""
        - ""
        - ""
        - ""
    tasks:
      - name: old data with empty new lines
        debug:
          var: mac_port

      - set_fact:
          new_mac_port: |
            {% set new_mac_port = [] %}
            {% for p in mac_port %}
            {% if p != "" %}
            {% set _ = new_mac_port.append(p) %}
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            {{ new_mac_port }}
        run_once: yes

      - name: filtered data without empty lines
        debug:
          var: new_mac_port
```

Now the value of `run_once: yes` will be

```
TASK [filtered data without empty lines] ***************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "new_mac_port": [
        "201    44a8.4227.c7ba    DYNAMIC     Gi1/0/13"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code which works !!

```
- set_fact:
        mac_port: "{{ comout | json_query('results[*].item.stdout') | list }}"

    - set_fact:
        new_mac_port: |
          {% set new_mac_port = [] %}
          {% for p in mac_port %}
          {% if p[0] != "" %}
          {% set _ = new_mac_port.append(p[0]) %}
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
          {{ new_mac_port }}
      run_once: yes
```